# How to access account.google.com's id_token from SessionStorage in Angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, session-storage

I am trying to get  id_token from the session storage in my angular app using

`sessionStorage.getItem('id_token');`

but it does not work.

Is there a way to access it?

Comment: Angular and AngularJs are two different things

Comment: Sorry my bad...updated the post